# Excel VBA - position of checkbox inside of the cell

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I cannot position my checkbox to the right side of the cell.

Macro adds button to specific cell to the left top corner, but when I want to Add also checkbox to the same cell it wont go to the right side, how can I do that ? Apparently the number 50 in the line Set chkbx is used to set the position. But my checkbox only goes to the left when I change it to the negative number. But it wont go to the right. How can I do it ?

```
Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(10, NewColumn), Cells(10, NewColumn))
Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, 0, 0)
With btn
  .OnAction = "Button_clicked"
  .Caption = "X"
  .Width = 15
  .Height = 12
  .Name = "Delete_button_" & x
End With
```

/*HERE IS THE CHECKBOX I WANT TO HAVE IN THE RIGHT UPPER CORNER*/

```
Set chkbx = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(t.Left, t.Top, 50, 0)
With chkbx
    .Name = "CheckBox_" & x
    .Caption = ""
End With
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Set chkbx = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(t.Left, t.Top, 0, 0)
With chkbx
    .Name = "CheckBox_" & x
    .Caption = ""
    .Left = t.Left + t.Width - .Width
End With
```

Comment: well nope, now its somewhere in the middle, and I tried changing the numbers, + and - and more but no luck, either its more on the left side or completely out of cell, in the next one

Comment: Add a statement `Debug.print .Width` before the `end with` - what is the width of the checkbox (should be 15.75) ?

Comment: Hmm. Then try something like `.Left = t.Left + t.Width - 16` and play with the number until it fits.

Comment: tried that, what is really strange is that I cannot find optimal number, e.g. I use  .Left = t.Left + 45 ... and its somewhere in the middle and when I use  .Left = t.Left + 47 its completely out of the cell

Comment: Do I understand it correct: You place a button in the sheet (cell) and on top of that the checkbox? Can you try without the button?

Comment: I dont want to put it on the top, makro does it and I dont know why, Button should be on the left side and checkbox should be on the right side of that one cell